# How use intent in android popup up window button to open another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am opening a MainActivity in android, when user click on assesment button after that app is getting stopped (actually i am trying to opening a popup window which has two buttons one was closing that popup window successfully but when i put an onclickListener on another button in popup window to open a new activity from that moment my whole popup code is not working.)

```
    assesment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_one, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

            //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GuestAssessment.class);
            //startActivityForResult(i, 2);
            //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, popup.class);
            //startActivity(i);

            popupTwoopen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Bnext);
            popupTwoopen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, popup_two.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            popupOneclose = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.Bclose);


            popupOneclose.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  popupWindow.dismiss();
                 }});


            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(assesment, 270, 120);

        }
    });`
```

logcat:

```
01-29 13:05:48.046: I/Adreno-EGL(13699): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
01-29 13:05:48.046: I/Adreno-EGL(13699): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
01-29 13:05:48.046: I/Adreno-EGL(13699): Build Date: 03/21/14 Fri
01-29 13:05:48.046: I/Adreno-EGL(13699): Local Branch: AU200+patches_03212014
01-29 13:05:48.046: I/Adreno-EGL(13699): Remote Branch: 
01-29 13:05:48.046: I/Adreno-EGL(13699): Local Patches: 
01-29 13:05:48.046: I/Adreno-EGL(13699): Reconstruct Branch: 
01-29 13:05:48.086: D/OpenGLRenderer(13699): Enabling debug mode 0
01-29 13:05:48.126: E/pix(13699): 683 390 266370
01-29 13:05:48.376: E/pix(13699): 683 390 266370
01-29 13:05:48.516: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8780K, 54% free 8613K/18448K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
01-29 13:05:48.536: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 47% free 9818K/18448K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
01-29 13:05:48.536: E/pix(13699): 683 453 309399
01-29 13:05:48.546: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 41% free 11027K/18448K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
01-29 13:05:48.556: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 28% free 13444K/18448K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
01-29 13:05:48.806: E/pix(13699): 683 453 309399
01-29 13:05:48.916: E/pix(13699): 683 455 310765
01-29 13:05:49.116: D/AndroidRuntime(13699): Shutting down VM
01-29 13:05:49.116: W/dalvikvm(13699): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416c7da0)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699): Process: com.sk.shri.spa, PID: 13699
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at com.sk.shri.spa.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:108)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
01-29 13:05:49.116: E/AndroidRuntime(13699):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 13:05:49.176: E/pix(13699): 683 455 310765
01-29 13:05:49.316: E/pix(13699): 683 453 309399
01-29 13:05:49.346: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13886K, 60% free 12289K/30592K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
01-29 13:05:49.356: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 53% free 14666K/30592K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
01-29 13:05:49.606: E/pix(13699): 683 453 309399
01-29 13:05:49.736: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6303K, 64% free 11179K/30592K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
01-29 13:05:49.756: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 60% free 12526K/30592K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
01-29 13:05:49.756: E/pix(13699): 683 505 344915
01-29 13:05:49.776: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 55% free 13873K/30592K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
01-29 13:05:50.106: E/pix(13699): 683 505 344915
01-29 13:05:50.296: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6997K, 55% free 13911K/30592K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
01-29 13:05:50.296: E/pix(13699): 683 512 349696
01-29 13:05:50.316: D/dalvikvm(13699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 46% free 16643K/30592K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
01-29 13:05:50.656: E/pix(13699): 683 512 349696
01-29 13:05:50.776: I/Process(13699): Sending signal. PID: 13699 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post the logcat which includes the exception and stacktrace and tell us where it is crashing.

Comment: you have NPE in `MainActivity.java:108` MainActivity class line 108,which line is that?

Comment: line 108 is:  popupTwoopen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, popup_two.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

Comment: trying to go to popup_two.class from MainActivity.this via intent.

Comment: David Wasser problem is in line 108 where i am using intent it is not going to another class. Line 108 is: 
 
line 108 is: popupTwoopen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, popup_two.class); startActivity(intent); } });